# Nextjs App Router: I want to make dynamic routes at root level in /app folder

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am working with below folder structure.

```
/app
   [..slug]
     /about-us
     /a/b/c
   page.js ('/',homepage)
```

My main problem is with generateMetadata, It is setting about-us metadata on Homepage.
I just want to know, is this good way to add dynamic routes at root level